# Event 'e' in Javascript Function's Parameter

Tags: javascript, function, events, parameters

My question is simple but little bit confusing for me that when we write code of `document.onclick` with function `function(e)` so why we put `e` into parameter even though function is not return anything in call back function's paramter because it's anonymous function so my point is that why we don't put `e` or `event` inside the function instead of parameter().

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i =0; i<divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].onclick = function(e){
        e = e || event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("Target " + target.className + ",this " + this.className);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'e' stands for 'Event'. This is on abject representing the event that was triggered and contains a lot of useful informations, like mouse cursor position when you clicked a button, or event modifiers keys such as Shift, Ctrl of Alt when you're inputing some text on an element with an eventListener.

Comment: More specifically, ``e`` is the data that is passed to the callback that is *called back* when the event occurs. ``e`` could be called ``Cake`` for all it matters, it would still get passed that data and contain event-related properties.

Comment: so why we don't put 'e' inside the function instead of parameter?